# Capture Video Frames

Tags: ios, iphone

I have written the code to capture video frames from here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html.

In `-(void)CaptureOutout()` delegate function, I am displaying the image in UIimageView by simply adding this line of code `[self.uiimage setImage:image]`. All is working fine but
the problem is that I want to continuously capture the video frames, but it captures only one video frames and display's it. The other video frame is captured when I close and reopens the app. This means the `CaptureOutout()` function is called only once, but I want to get the continuous video frames and display them as a continuously on image view. Can anybody solve this problem?

Comment: you can use NSTimer for continuous capturing images.

Comment: Check this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16083786/900024)